# How does a process know that semaphore is available

Tags: c, unix, ipc, semaphore

```
I have a very basic doubt.
```

when a process is waiting on a semaphore , it goes into sleep state. 
    So no way it can poll the semaphore value.

Does kernel poll the semaphore value and if available sends a signal to all process waiting for it ? If so, wont it be too much overhead for the kernel.

Or does the signal() call internally notifies all the process waiting for the semaphore. 
    Please let me know on this.

Comment: Read [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) & [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operating system schedules the process once more when the operating system is told by another process that it has done with the semaphore.

Semaphores are just one of the ways of interacting with the OS scheduler.

The kernel doesn't poll the semaphore; it doesn't need to. Every time a process calls `sem_post()` (or equivalent), that involves interaction with the kernel. What the kernel does during the `sem_post()` is look up whatever processes have previously called `sem_wait()` on the same semaphore. If one or more processes have called `sem_wait()`, it picks the process with the highest priority and schedules it. This shows up as that `sem_wait()` finally returning and that process carries on executing.

**How This is Implemented Under the Hood**

Fundamentally the kernel needs to implement something called an "atomic test and set". That is an operation where by the value of some variable can be tested and, if a certain condition is met (such as the value == 0) the variable value is altered (e.g. value = 1). If this succeeds, the kernel will do one thing, (like schedule a process), if this does not (because the condition value==0 was false) the kernel will do something difference (like put a process on the do-not-schedule list). The 'atomic' part is that this decision is made without anything else being able to look at and change the same variable at the same time.

There's several ways of doing this. One is to suspend all processes (or at least all activity within the kernel) so that nothing else is testing the value of the variable at the same time. That's not very fast.

For example, the Linux kernel once had something called the Big Kernel Lock. I don't know if this was used to process semaphore interactions, but that's the kind of thing that OSes used to have for atomic test & sets.

These days CPUs have atomic test & set op codes, which is a lot faster. The good ole' Motorola 68000 had one of these a long time ago; it took CPUs like the PowerPC and the x86 many, many years to get the same kind of instruction.

If you root around inside linux you'll find mention of `futexes`. a futex is a fast mutex - it relies on a CPU's test/set instruction to implement a fast `mutex` semaphore.

**Post a Semaphore in Hardware**

A variation is a mailbox semaphore. This is a special variation on a semaphore that is extremely useful in some system types where hardware needs to wake up a process at the end of a DMA transfer. A mailbox is a special location in memory which when written to will cause an interrupt to be raised. This can be turned into a semaphore by the kernel because when that interrupt is raised, it goes through the same motions as it would had something called `sem_post()`.

This is incredibly handy; a device can `DMA` a large amount of data to some pre-arranged buffer, and top that off with a small `DMA` transfer to the mail box. The kernel handles the interrupt, and if a process has previously called `sem_wait()` on the mailbox semaphore the kernel schedules it. The process, which also knows about this pre-arranged buffer, can then process the data.

On a real time DSP systems this is very useful, because it's very fast and very low latency; it allows a process to receive data from some device with very little delay. The alternative, to have a full up device driver stack that uses `read()` / `write()` to transfer data from the device to the process is incredibly slow by comparison.

**Speed**

The speed of semaphore interactions depends entirely on the OS.

For OSes like Windows and Linux, the context switch time is fairly slow (in the order of several microseconds, if not tens of microseconds). Basically this means that when a process calls something like `sem_post()`, the kernel is doing a lot of different things whilst it has the opportunity before finally returning control to the process(es). What it's doing during this time could be, well, almost anything!

If a program has made use of a lot threads, and they're all rapidly interacting between themselves using semaphores, quite a lot of time is lost to the `sem_post()` and `sem_wait()`. This places an emphasis on doing a decent amount of work once a process has returned from `sem_wait()` before calling the next `sem_post()`.

However on OSes like VxWorks, the context switch time is lightning fast. That is there's very little code in the kernel that gets run when sem_post() is called. The result is that a semaphore interaction is a lot more efficient. Moreover, and OS like VxWorks is written in such a way so as to guarantee that the time take to do all this `sem_post()` / `sem_wait()` work is *constant*.

This influences the architecture of one's software on these systems. On VxWorks, where a context switch is cheap, there's very little penalty in having a large number of threads all doing quite small tasks. On Windows / Linux there's more of an emphasis on the opposite.

This is why OSes like VxWorks are excellent for hard real time applications, and Windows / Linux are not.

The Linux PREEMPT_RT patch set in part aims to improve the latency of the linux kernel during operations like this. For example, it pushes a lot of device interrupt handlers (device drivers) up into kernel threads; these are scheduled almost just like any other thread. The idea is to reduce the amount of work that is being done by the kernel (and have more done by kernel threads), so that the work it still has to do itself (such as handling `sem_post()` / `sem_wait()`) takes less time and is more consistent about how long this takes. It still not a hard guarantee of latency, but it's a pretty good improvement. This is what we call a soft-realtime kernel. The impact though is that overall throughput of the machine can be lower.

**Signals**

Signals are nasty, horrible things that really get in the way of using things like sem_post() and sem_wait(). I avoid them like the plague.

If you are on a Linux platform and you do have to use signals, take a serious long look at `signalfd` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd)). This is a far better way of dealing with signals because you can choose to accept them at a convenient time (simply by called `read()`), instead of having to handle them as soon as they occur. Certainly if you're using `epoll()` or `select()` anywhere at all in a program then `signalfd` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This means that kernel does maintain semaphore:Process id mapping at some place and this will be looked up on sem_post () call.

Comment: @CodeTry, you're welcome. Absolutely yes, the OS maintains mappings of semaphore:process ids. When a process calls something like sem_close(), that's the process asking the kernel to remove the process from that mapping. If the kernel notices that the mapping list is now empty, it will dispose of the semaphore itself. With named semaphores (they exist in the file system too), they can hang around after the process(es) themselves have all closed. Start the processes up again and the semaphore is still there, in its last state! It's important to remember to unlink named semaphores...

Comment: got it. Thankyou.

Comment: 8086 has `lock xchg`, which allows you to atomically set a byte or word to a new value and read the old value.  On 386 and later, `xchg` with memory implicitly has a `lock` prefix, so it's always an atomic RMW.  It's what C++ implementations use to implement `std::atomic_flag`'s `test_and_set`.   https://godbolt.org/z/cenGo4G5G  because it's slightly faster than `lock bts` which test-and-sets a single bit within a word.  (Which was new in 386, launched in 1985, so I assume that's what you're thinking of with "many, many years" to talk about the 5 to 6 years between 68k launch and 386 launch?)

Comment: As for PowerPC, I'd be surprised if they didn't have a way to implement atomic test-and-set or other sync primitive pretty early, since as a RISC you do need a special instruction to support it.  On a single-core CISC, you normally already have memory-destination RMW instructions. 
 Since instructions are normally atomic wrt. interrupts on the same core, that's sufficient for pre-emptive multitasking and interrupt handling.  For multi-core, you need something like PowerPC's LL/SC `lwarx` / `stwcx` (https://godbolt.org/z/K7YTT556e) or x86 / 68k / ARMv8.1 single-instruction RMWs.

Comment: What 68k (but not 68000) had that was unique was `cas2`; compare-and-swap on two separate memory locations.  But that was dropped, and other mainstream ISAs didn't adopt it, because it was very expensive (in performance) to implement.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap .  In modern x86, you can only do that on CPUs with transactional memory that isn't disabled by microcode updates, or with software locking.

Comment: @PeterCordes Hello Peter, I'm really referring to VME with multiple processor boards. VME being 68000's bus brought out to backplane, it's opcode for atomic test and set could work to off-board addresses. With processors like PowerPC 601, 604, they needed a bridge chip to connect to VME and therefore their T&S opcodes didn't reach off board, though the bridge could be programmed to do it. Technically I'm wrong - even 601 did SMP - but the practical reality I just about remember was that multiple CPUs meant VME, neutering any SMP capability CPUs had (unless they were 68000).

Comment: Interesting, so the ISA had the instructions, but the interconnect between multiple CPUs didn't respect cache coherency properly?  Must have been hard to program at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes that's basically how it was. The bridge chips for PowerPC could support mailbox interrupts (painful in PowerPC - only 1 external interrupt line), and you could mark off memory one had exposed to the VME bus as not-cached. You'd be dealing with multiple address spaces - local, what that'd appear as on the bus (#2), what that'd appear as when mapped by another card (#3, and because it's mapped differently by subsequent CPU cards, #4, #5, #6) etc. Took a certain degree of mental agility to communicate a memory address from one CPU to another!

Comment: @PeterCordes and it's still like this today, with modern equivalents like OpenVPX. These days though bus snooping helps, so you can cache "shared" memory. E.g. one has a card running 2 CPUs in an SMP configuration, with memory being exposed to the fabric (aka bus), and fabric chips shunting data very quickly inter-card. The fabric now is lots of Ethernet, but one doesn't use ip, tcp. You go this way when the SMP interconnect for CPUs doesn't support enough CPUs. It's like Fujitsu's Tofu fabric on their supers, except they build it right into CPU silicon, not added on as a PCIe dev in the card.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252339/discussion-between-bazza-and-peter-cordes).